# how to retrieve any restrictions on a youtube video?

Tags: python, youtube-api, gdata

i am working on getting videos from YouTube. This link has been very helpful:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python#code_printVideoEntry

Except that i couldn't really make a solution out of finding out how i can understand (and display to the user if possible) which restrictions apply to a specific video (represented by the gData object YouTubeVideoEntry).
furthermore, does anyone know if the method YouTubeVideoEntry.GetSwfUrl() is infact a way of knowing whether the video is embeddable or not?

Would appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: Guys, doesn't anyone know anything about this issue? I'd love to know if someone out there stumbled upon this issue before...